# Object Library Like Strikethrough In Swift?

Tags: swift, user-interface, object, controls

I want to make UI like this:

[image: 2 lines of text and with something like strikethrough between it]

Description: 2 lines of text and with something like strikethrough between it

How can I do it (strikethrough), which object?

Comment: What have you tried ?  SO is for you to get errors fixed in your code, not for someone else to write it for you.

Comment: it just UI have something lịke strikethrough, and I have no idea for it! Could you tell me which object can do it, i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var TopBorder = CALayer()
    TopBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    TopBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 3.0);
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(TopBorder)
```